# VS 2017 .NET Core IISExpress setting up multiple applications to run under same host site

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, asp.net-core-webapi

Ive searched all over for an answer to this - Prior to converting some of my applications to .NET Core I could do the below config in applicationhost.config for IISExpress so when I hit F5 in Visual Studio all the applications (in different solutions) started up in ISSExpress and any Web api calls etc.. between applications would work (e.g. api1 could talk to api2)

```
<sites>
    <site name="test" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\codepath" />
        </application>
        <application path="/api1" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\codepath\api1" />
        </application>
        <application path="/api2" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\codepath\api2" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
<!-- other settings  relevant to your installation of IISExpress-->
</sites>
```

I cant get this to work when they are .NET Core apps - I think it maybe because It does not seem to allow two .NET Core apps to share the same applicationPool - On F5 it will automatically create a new applicationPool and update the config accordingly. When I look at IIS Express in the tray it has only started up the current application.

Does anyone know how to get round this? or create the same effect when dealing with .NET Core apps? - At the moment I have to run multiple solutions at the same time and It really slows down local debugging for anything that interacts with other applications

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am curious if you ever solved this?